# FreeBSD ports: remove build dependencies after installing port

Tags: freebsd-ports

Is there any way to remove build dependencies of the port after installing it?

Many ports use exotic tools for building and these tools are not used anymore when port is builded and installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My suggestion would be [`pkg_cutleaves`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=pkg_cutleaves&stype=all&sektion=all) (available in the ports collection), or [`pkg-orphan`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=pkg-orphan&stype=all&sektion=all) -- Both of these do the same basic thing (list packages that aren't referred to as a dependency by any other package, and ask you what to do).

I wouldn't bother though: The build dependencies will just have to be rebuilt and reinstalled when you upgrade the port, and they generally don't take up huge amounts of room.  Leaving them won't hurt you unless your system is severely disk-space constrained.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the packages?

Comment: Packages are often are a bit older and some ports need to be configured before build, so packages are not often and option for me. System binary updates are cool though.